# Is there any way to launch appropriate activity of my app when appropriate NFC Tag is scanned?

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I'd like to open my app on NFC Signal with appropriate activity.

When Tag is formatted as URI, it works and changes my activity but only when the app is open. when it's closed, it doesn't open the app.
when Tag is formatted as Text, it just opens my app but doesn't change it to appropriate activity and shows me that data is null.

How can I open my specified activity of my app on NFC Tag signal and which format should I use for tag? URI or Text?

should I change `<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />`  in my manifest, if I use URI for tags or not?

here is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ge.softservice.nfcwithactivties">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!--For processing data from NFC Tag (launchMode)-->

    <application
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Menu2Activity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Menu1Activity">




        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />

                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
     package ge.softservice.nfcwithactivties

import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.Intent
import android.nfc.*
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.MimeTypeFilter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

    const val TAG = "MainActivity"

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var nfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null
    var nfcPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null

    private var KEY_LOG_TEXT = "logText"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)
        val nfcSupported = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nfc_support)
        val nfcEnabled = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nfc_enabled)

        // Restore saved text if available
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            text.text = savedInstanceState.getCharSequence(KEY_LOG_TEXT)
        }

        // Check if NFC is supported and enabled
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            nfcSupported.append("your phone has not NFC")
        } else {
            nfcSupported.append(" Your phone has NFC")
        }

        if (nfcAdapter?.isEnabled != null) {
            nfcEnabled.append(" you have NFC turned on")
        } else {
            nfcEnabled.append(" your NFC is turned off")
        }

        nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            Intent(this, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)

        if (intent?.data.toString() == "1. " ) {
            openMenu1()
            text.append(intent?.data.toString())
        } else if (intent?.data.toString() == "2. ") {
            openMenu2()
            text.append(intent?.data.toString())
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ups.. Unknown tag detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            text.append(intent?.data.toString())
        }

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Get all NDEF discovered intents
        // Makes sure the app gets all discovered NDEF messages as long as it's in the foreground.
        nfcAdapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, null, null)
        // Alternative: only get specific HTTP NDEF intent
        //nfcAdapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, nfcIntentFilters, null)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        // Disable foreground dispatch, as this activity is no longer in the foreground
        nfcAdapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }

    fun openMenu1() {
        val intent = Intent(this, Menu1Activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun openMenu2() {
        val intent = Intent(this, Menu2Activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
    }
```

Thanks a lot, in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you have a very crude method of parsing the data from the card in the `onNewIntent` method.

You should be parsing the Intent data properly for NDEF messages from the NFC card.

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#obtain-info on how to do this.

You also needed to first think through about the NFC data formats, there is not enough info in the question to answer this precisely, but there are two possibilities:-

1) You don't control the data on the card, then need to understand the data format and adjust you reading of the Intent in `onNewIntent` to match and using `toString` is not an option as there is no guarantee that it will return the part of the NFC data you need to read.

You should gain a good understand of all the option of NDEF messages for this.

If you are having trouble with NDEF data formats use the `NXPinfo` App to read the cards https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.taginfolite and put details in new questions.

2) You have control of the data on the card, I then suggest you write the cards using a custom mimeType e.g. "signal/menu" or other suitable combination, this will reduce the likelihood of other apps or the system trying to handle your cards. It will also make parsing the data easier because you know the format of the data in the NDEF message.

Comment: I have control of the data on the card. Thanks a lot. I'll try